# Does this Wiring Diagram Create ground loop Issues?

Tags: electrical, switch, grounding, generator, solar

I have a two x LV6548 Pure Sine Wave 6,500W Inverter/Chargers - 13,000W Continuous Output 120/240V Inverters that I wish to integrate with my Subpanels in the house for Off-grid with Main Utility Backup. Subpanel-1 feeds Subpanel-2. Inverters ground back to the main panel with 2x60A/120V AC In coming from Main Utility Panel (for AC Charging switched by inverter if PV is off), and then Inverters Feed the subpanel-1 via 125A/240V Breaker. The Main Utility also feeds the subpanel-1 through the 200A breaker. Subpanel-1 Ground connects off Ground Busbar to both Main utility Panel and Inverters. Also, Subpanel-1 feeds Subpanel-2 via a second 125A/240V Breaker, and ground from Subpanel-2 connects back to Subpanel-1. I plan a Gen Interlock Kit to require Main Breaker Off while Gen Breaker On and vice versus.

My big question is about the Ground configuration. I expect any short-circuit or lightning strike to follow least path of resistance direct back to the main Panel from Subpanel-2 >> Subpanel-1 >> Main Utility whether in Main-On or Generator-On at Subpanel-1 Breakers, as that would be path of least resistance. And if Inverters are shorted or lightning strike, current would travel direct to Main Utility ground. Since Subpanel-1 is grounded to Main. Utility, would it be best to 1) Disconnect the ground back to  Inveerters? or 2) Maintain both the ground connections from Subpanel-1 to the inverters and Main utility Panel? **See Diagram:** [image: CircuitDiagram]

Comment: What make and model are your inverters?

Comment: Hit "Flag...Moderator intervention" and ask mods to merge your accounts. That way you won't have to get permission to do an edit to your own question, and will be able to comment to your own question. (Because you reset your cookies or changed browsers, you created a second account, hence your troubles. Registering to an email/google/facebook fixes this.)

Comment: Or, just read and follow [these instructions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I submitted my electrical drawings as-is and the Permit was approved. So, I am guessing not issues with the grounding. :)  To answer your question on inverters they are LV6548 Hybrid inverters by  MPP Solar (Rich Solar). AC In from PV/Batt/Main is handled by switching bult into the Inverters and the service panels are grounded back to the inverters and in turn to the main service panel. And, if inverter breaker is turned off and Main breaker on in SubPanel 1a the ground is direct back to main from 1a. This to isolate the inverters/PV/Battery system for servicing.